# 2:1 Diametric rotation matrix for a 2D orthographic projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

I asked this question in the game dev stack exchange, but didn't get a response. This is more of a math question with an application in game development so I hope it's alright if I ask here.

I'm trying to implement a 2D isometric game, well diametric with a 2:1 pixel ratio. To do this I have a 2D image of a cube I drew with pixel editing software, where for every pixel up, there are two pixels to the right. I'd like to post an image of it but I don't have the reputation for it. [It looks something like this](http://gas13.ru/v3/tutorials/e0.gif). From what I read this is called dimetric projection, and is composed of two axis rotations, one is 45 degrees about the x axis and the other one is arctan(1/2) around the z. [Here is some more detail.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_video_game_graphics)

I tried to calculate the rotation matrix, but when I use this to convert an (x,y,z) in Cartesian coordinates to isometric world space coordinates(x`,y`,z`) the cube images do not align correctly with each other, leading me to believe I am missing something else to this problem, or my math is wrong. I have found ways online to fudge it, but they all ignore the z axis which I require. I'm not sure if I did my rotation matrix correctly but here it is:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & -1/\sqrt(2) \\
    1\sqrt{10} & 2/\sqrt{5} & -1/\sqrt{10} \\
    -1\sqrt{2/5} & 1/\sqrt{5} & \sqrt{2/5} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Edit: I can now upload pictures of what I have working, notice how the images are offset. The blue coordinates are the Cartesian positions before the isometric transformations.

[image: Iso projection]

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to compute an appropriate projection matrix?

Comment: That is correct @amd

Comment: Can you first scale so the 2 to 1 pixel complication is removed from the problem? Then reformulate based on that? Are you wanting to rotate the cube about its center? Can you express as two successive rotations (factoring)?

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate about the scaling first part? I have enough rep now to upload images so I added a picture to help better visualize my problem. The cube also isn't truly a cube, it's an 2D image  in 3d space. @JohnLWinters

Comment: Yes I voted for your question. Pretend you have a 1 to 1 pixel instead of a 2 to 1 to simplify and focus on the rotations.

Comment: Is the discrepancy that you’re concerned about that the oblique (2:1) edges don’t exactly have a slope of 1/2 and aren’t parallel to each other, or is the problem that you’re concerned about the fact that the cube images don’t line up nicely? (The two could have the same cause.) What do the coordinates scribbled on the cube tops in the image represent?

Comment: Two other notes: 1) You appear to be using a perspective projection instead of a parallel (orthographic) projection. This will cause most parallel lines in the scene not to be parallel in the image. 2) If the tops of the cubes are coplanar, then it’s impossible to get the occlusion seen in the example image irrespective of getting the correct rotation or using the correct projection. Check your model. You certainly shouldn’t expect them to pack together nicely in the image if they’re not packed in the scene.